# Автоматизация вызова функции

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Имеется функция очистки определённого диапазона таблицы в определённый день недели. Задача: автоматизировать вызов функции через триггер. Я столкнулся с рядом проблем. Основные из них: таблицей пользуется несколько сотен человек, из разных часовых поясов. Хочется сделать вызов функции при изменении даты в московском часовом поясе или в определённое время каждый, при этом без привязки локального времени ПК каждого кто редактирует таблицу. Возможно ли создать триггер по серверному времени Гугла?

Answer (score 1):

Самое выгодное в данной ситуации - это установка триггера программно с указанием временной зоны через метод `inTimezone`

```
function USER_ACTION_SETUP_TRIGGER(){
    // Schedule the trigger to execute
    // at noon every day in the US/Pacific time zone
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
      .timeBased()
      .atHour(12)
      .everyDays(1)
      .inTimezone("America/Los_Angeles")
      .create();
}
```

Вы должны однажды запустить этот триггер из окна редактора кода.

Справка [Class ClockTriggerBuilder  |  Apps Script  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#inTimezone(String))